# ActiveMQ Artemis and multiple DLQs

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have many queues, i.e

```
my.queue.no.1
my.queue.no.2
my.queue.no.3
my.queue.no.4
```

And I want to redirect unsuccessful messages to DLQ, but I don't want to mix messages from all queues to a one DLQ.

Is it possible to have multiple DLQs?

i.e

```
my.queue.no.1
my.queue.no.dlq.1
my.queue.no.2
my.queue.no.dlq.2
my.queue.no.3
my.queue.no.dlq.3
my.queue.no.4
my.queue.no.dlq.4
```

P.S I'm using Artemis 2.16.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis can automatically create the defined dead-letter-address and a corresponding dead-letter queue when a message is undeliverable enabling the `auto-create-dead-letter-resources` [address setting](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-settings.html). The `dead-letter-queue-prefix` [address setting](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-settings.html) can be used to define a prefix used for automatically created dead-letter queues, i.e. to create `DLQ.my.queue.no.NNN` queues under the `DLA` address:

```
<address-settings>
   <address-setting match="my.queue.no.#">
      <dead-letter-address>DLA</dead-letter-address>
      <auto-create-dead-letter-resources>true</auto-create-dead-letter-resources>
      <dead-letter-queue-prefix>DLQ.</dead-letter-queue-prefix>
      ...
```

Comment: @JustinBertram yes, you are right, `auto-create-dead-letter-resources` needs to be true, thanks, I have updated the answer.